# wordpress theme (bridge) pages on top of each other:(

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with my WP website if i set my pages to public.
all my pages will get posted on the homepage how can i fix this problem the theme support theme takes ages

is it possible to separate the pages from each other please let me know

[image: The page should start where the slider is everything on top is the second page]

Comment: I think that this would be down to how the theme works. Usually a theme will show the latest posts on the home page by default - which may be what the theme is doing.  Alternatively you can set the homepage as a static page in "settings" > "Reading"

Comment: yes i got i had changed the settings but thx